# How to require an attribute in a custom component in angular

Tags: angularjs, binding, attributes, require, angular-components

I am developing a custom component and I would like to set some required condition on some input attributes. Is there a way to do so?

For example, say that the component is "myComp" and the two attributes are "required" and "optional" I would like that:

```
<my-comp required="value" optional="value"></my-comp>
```

this run successfully

```
<my-comp required="value"></my-comp>
```

this run smooth also but this:

```
<my-comp optional="value"></my-comp>
```

sends some kind of error in console telling that the attribute "required" is of course "required".

At the moment I am using a typescript version of angularJs (version 1.5.x) and declaring the attributes inside a bindings object like this:

```
export class MyCompComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public template: string = '<p>TEMPLATE</p>';
    public controller: Function = MyCompController;
    public bindings: any = {
        required: '@',
        optional: '@'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the attribute in the controller:

```
  app.controller("MyCompController", function($element,$attrs) {
    if (!$attrs.required) {
      console.error("BAD my-comp ",$element[0],
            "my-comp component missing 'required' attribute");
    }
  })
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/cO3c07lfBtqx4SsVuQkv?p=preview)

Comment: what's the interface for $element and $attrs ? 
For example for $log I use ng.ILogService